# DaggerAppComponent Not found

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to build the project which has a large dependency graph and uses dagger 2. 
I use following dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
```

I am not able to build the app because it shows 50 errors like

```
    cannot find symbol class DaggerAddressComponent 
    cannot find symbol class DaggerAddToCartActivityComponent
    cannot find symbol class DaggerPaymentFragmentComponent
    cannot find symbol variable GlideApp

    ...More 50 like this
```

All the DaggerComponent are not found and I also don't see any dagger classes created in generatedJava Folder.
I know this may happen due to syntax error, but I checked all the modules and don't see any.

Does Someone know how to fix this? Or guide me on how to track down any mistakes in my modules/components. gradle log does not show anything related to dagger so how can we know where is the mistake?

Comment: Gradle doesn't show full error output and you might miss useful error due to this. I once encountered this problem and this thread was helpful. https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/306

Comment: Do you use Java or Kotlin?

Comment: I am using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After whole day and going through every line of my code, I found that I have one duplicate method in my view interface, which happened during merge. Removed that and all the things were good.

It is strange how Android studio shows all the class not found error and does't show that error. I know it is a silly mistake but it is confusing to find the real error if you don't see that error in logs.